# SwiftUI Change color theme programmatically

Tags: swiftui

I have .light and .dark theme.

In preview (MyContainer_Previews) I can change them by:

```
ForEach([.light,.dark], id: \.self) { theme in

            Group {
                ...
            } 
            .environment(\.colorScheme, theme) //This line
        }
 ...
```

How can I change app theme on the fly (f.e. button action).
I tri to change it in SceneDelegate:

```
 let contentView = ContentView()
 contentView.environment(\.colorScheme, .dark) //Not work
```

Comment: Is not the scheme controlled by a iPhone user?

Comment: I need to override it. If user want always dark or light.

Comment: I answered your question already then

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reactive:

```
    return NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0) {
            ...
        }

    } 
    .environment(\.colorScheme, appState.options.theme == .light ? .light : .dark)
```

Comment: And what if I don't want my view to be inside of a navigation view?

Answer (score 2):

Some one told me if you put you code in NavagationView, you can use your `enviorment` to change the scheme.

```
var body: some View {


NavigationView{
   //Your view here
}}
```

`let contentView = ContentView()
 contentView.environment(\.colorScheme, .dark) //works now`

```
  UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environment(\.colorScheme, .light)

  struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
   NavigationView{
       Text("!")
    }}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and this code seems to work for me.

```
ForEach([.light,.dark], id: \.self) { theme in
    Group {
        ...
    } 
    .preferredColorScheme(theme)
}
```

...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).